# Where I can view Rally WSAPI source code

Tags: svn, github, rally

I was fascinated by Rally's WSAPI which made me ponder what Technologies rally uses internally to make their WS API object model so rich.Do they use search engines like Solr or Lucene, Elastic Search underneath ? Where can I view the Source code of Rally WSAPI for learning ?

PS : I am talking about actual Rally WSAPI and not about Rally WSAPI toolkits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While API toolkits source is in [this github repo](https://github.com/RallyTools) Rally WS API source is not available. You may explore WS API to the extent it is documented [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/).

Comment: I have explored the RallyTools Repo. I was more keen to look at the source code of WS API.Do you know if they are going to publish a read only repo for the source code ?

Comment: There are no such plans.